# Vuetify: v-text-field for days:hours:minutes?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I was curious to know if there is any chance of formatting a v-text-field so that it not only allows hours and minutes to be chosen, but also days.

I’m currently looking at the Vuetify documentation for text-fields, which shows the following solution:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icon-events

```
<v-text-field
   label="Label Text"
   value="12:30:00"
   type="time"
   suffix="PST"
></v-text-field>
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to choose days:hours:minutes, instead of hours:minutes:seconds.
Is there any way to manipulate the text-field in this manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify doesn't provide one component that does both, but you could use one each of types `date` and `time`:

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="vdate"
  label="DATE"
  type="date"
></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
  v-model="vtime"
  label="TIME"
  type="time"
  suffix="EST"
></v-text-field>
```

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/YzpWMWg)